# How to I create two variables by splitting a string in bash/zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to input something like "New York, USA" and get $city as "new-york" and $co as "usa"

```
cotime() {
  input=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr ' ' '-')
  arr=(${input//,/ })
  city=${arr[0]}
  co=${arr[1]}
  echo $city
  echo $co
  xidel -s "https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/${co}/${city}" -e '//*[@id="ct"]/text()'
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
$ cotime 'new york,usa'

new-york usa
```

which isn't quite correct...

Comment: What *would* the correct output be?

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/cgoKTV

Comment: @Shawn It looks like the city and country should be on separate lines in the output.

Comment: Did you make any changes to `IFS` in your script?

Comment: You have this tagged with both `bash` and `zsh`. Which shell are you actually using? They have different behavior regarding word splitting after expanding variables.

Comment: i'd like a solution that works in both if possible. but i'm using zsh

Comment: The issue is how `zsh` handles word-splitting (or doesn't). "words of unquoted parameters are not automatically split on whitespace unless the option `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is set;"  See [Zsh Manual - Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) What you have works fine in bash (though your should replace the command substitution for `input` with `input="${1// /-}"` and for case, `input="${input,,}"` to avoid the unnecessary subshells.

Answer (score 2):

Use `read` (and in `zsh`, the expansion modifier `:l`) to make this simpler.

```
cotime () {
  IFS=, read city country <<< "$1:l"
  city=${city// /-}
  xidel -s "https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/${co}/${city}" -e '//*[@id="ct"]/text()'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not let `xidel` process your input if you're already using it?

```
$ xidel -se '
  let $location:=lower-case(read()) => replace("\s","-") =>
                 tokenize(",") => reverse() => join("/")
  return (
    $location,
    doc("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/"||$location)//span[@id="ct"]
  )
'
New York,USA   # <-- Input you have to type, which Xidel reads with read().
usa/new-york   # <-- Xidel's output.
17:40:31       # <-- Xidel's output.
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the good old "cut":

```
input='new-york,usa'
city=$(echo $input |cut -d, -f1)
co=$(echo $input |cut -d, -f2)
if [ $city == $co ]; then city=''; fi
echo $city, $co
new-york, usa
```

Comment: Is it possible that city is empy? ie: support just passing `uk` instead of `london, uk`

Comment: Yes, if input='uk' then both $city and $co gets 'uk'. It would then just require a simple test to make $city an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it would be simpler to construct your URL directly with AWK using the comma as seperator.

```
theURL=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr ' ' '-' | awk -F',' '{ print "https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/" $2 "/" $1 }')
echo $theURL
xidel -s $theURL
```

This gives the following URL which works.

https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/new-york

Answer (score 0):

```
localtime() {
  input=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr ' ' '-')
        if [[ $input =~ "," ]]; then
                city=${input%%,*}
                country=${${input#*,}%%,*}
                location="${country}/${city}"
        else
                country=${input}
                location="${country}"
        fi
  echo $location
  xidel -s "https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/${location}" -e '//*[@id="ct"]/text()'
}
```